# Is it possible to automate the winding up of a Clockwork Engine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

The clockwork engines in the 1.5.2 version of Forestry provide essentially unlimited power at the cost of winding them with right-clicking. Is there any way to automate these, maybe with turtles or some other contraption? I can see how this would be very overpowered if mass produced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no by design, for exactly the reason you cited, (the developer explicitly removed the ability from turtle to be able to right click them I heard)

however an auto-fueled low-tier steam engine row can be powered by a small tree farm easily